# How to filter a dd/mm/yyyy date from a custom field in a query

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, filters, date-time, wpdb

I'm trying to build a query in order to sort some posts by a date custom field, where the dates are formatted dd/mm/yyyy.

It works by querying the database directly with `get_results` like in this example :

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_cutom_date'
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC
";
```

But, I would like to transpose this behavior to a `WP_Query`, using a `posts_where` filter. I got as far as this :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_date'
); 

function filter_orderby( $orderby = '' ) {  
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby .= " ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC ";
    return $orderby;
}

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_orderby' );
```

But it doesn't seem to return anything. what am I missing ?

Comment: Do you have the resulting SQL query that gets executed? Filter on [`posts_request`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/query.php#L2596) and `var_dump()` what gets passed, or install [the Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) with [`SAVEQUERIES`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis) enabled. I think the problem is that you don't have to specify `ORDER BY` yourself.

Comment: @Jan, The Debug bar is great, thanks a lot for that. And yes there is an error in the SQL. The thing is there are 2 ORDER statements, one default (I guess) and the one I add in my filter : `ORDER BY cs_posts.post_date DESC ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(cs_postmeta.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC` How can I remove the `ORDER BY cs_posts.post_date DESC` ?

Comment: @Jan, if I remove `ORDER BY` the result is the same, I get an error. I also tried with `AND`, for ex :`ORDER BY cs_posts.post_date DESC AND STR_TO_DATE(cs_posts.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y')`, but with no chance. Now I'm wondering, the filter lets you only _add_ things to the query ? It's impossible to overwrite the defaults ?

Comment: @myself, of course it is, by using "=" instead of ".=", as usual in php, duh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter on `posts_orderby` should return a string that does not begin with `ORDER BY`, WordPress [will add that itself](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/query.php#L2587).

By default WordPress will filter by `post_date`. If you don't want that, you should **overwrite** the order clause, not append to it. So your filter should look like this:

```
function filter_orderby( $orderby ) {  
    global $wpdb;
    return " STR_TO_DATE({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC ";
}
```